# fuzzy string match python

Tags: python, sql, string, fuzzy-search

I'm looking for a function in python that works exactly like '%' does in SQL for matching strings. I need this to match some strings that have weird spacing due to the way they were exported so I'll need to put % in between every single word to find the strings that I want.

example:

"Hello how are you"

"Hello how are      you"

"Hello        how     are you"

"  Hello   how are you"

I would like to use the sql way of matching strings to "%Hello%how%are%you%"

Comment: Try the `fnmatch` module or (for more sophisticated matching) `re` module.

Comment: I don't understand your case. Could you add examples?

Answer (score 0):

Please explain more, But i think you mean this :

```
def re_string(your_string):

    renew_string = your_string.split(' ')

    buffer_result = []
    for words in renew_string:
        if words.replace(' ', '') == '':
            pass
        else:
            buffer_result.append(words)

    last_data = '%'.join(buffer_result)
    return last_data


print(re_string("Hello how are you"))
print(re_string(" Hello how are you"))
print(re_string(" Hello    how are          you"))
print(re_string("  Hello   how   are you "))
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
>> Hello%how%are%you
>> Hello%how%are%you
>> Hello%how%are%you
>> Hello%how%are%you
```